# Regex to match all characters in a string except a certain character

Tags: python, regex

I'm using python, re.match to match. I want to match all the strings that have 4 characters not counting the ː symbol (it's an international phonetic alphabet symbol).

So the string "niːdi" should be matched. Regex should count it as 4 characters, not 5, because the ː symbol isn't counted.

So far, I have this. What should I add to make it not count the ː symbol ?

```
regex = "^.{1,5}$"
```

I don't want to delete the ː symbol from any of my strings. It's important that it stays in the data.

Comment: If you need further help, please drop a comment describing the current issue

Comment: Is the [purpose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/133817) of the regex just to check the length of the string (ignoring any triangular colons), or is it needed for any other task?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
regex = "^(?=.{1,5}$)[^ː]*(?:ː[^ː]*)?$"
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{1,5}$)` - the length is from 1 to 5
- `[^ː]*` - zero or more chars other than `ː`
- `(?:ː[^ː]*)?` - an optional sequence of `ː` and zero or more chars other than `ː`
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

For the regex to match anything that has one to two characters, ':', then one to two characters, you could use something like this: `^.{1,2}:.{1,2}$`
If you need it to be two:two, you can simplify the regex like this: `^.{2}:.{2}$`

I'm not sure about the character count issue, since the `:` is a char even though for your data it doesn't add value. Maybe you can subtract 1 from the count for each match you get

Good luck!

Comment: The problem is that the : symbol can occur no times, once or sometimes twice

Comment: @aliencode: any requirements (such as the number of times a triangular colon is allowed to appear) should be mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
regex = "^(:*[^:]:*){4}$"
```